# What’s wrong with this proof that a square is diffeomorphic to a circle?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, fake-proofs, diffeomorphism

I am studying the rigorous definition of manifolds and diffeomorphisms, and am confused about the following. Intuition would suggest a square is *not* diffeomorphic to a circle because the square has sharp corners which are not differentiable, whereas the circle does not. (I have also heard people make statements along these lines.)

On the other hand, I am free to equip the square with charts that make it smooth. In fact, any reasonable way I can imagine to cover the square with charts leads to smooth transition maps, just like for the circle. The charts have no knowledge of the square's "corners."

So is the square in fact diffeomorphic to the circle, and if so, what do people mean when they talk about shapes with "sharp corners" not being smooth? (To be clear, I'm talking about the boundaries of these shapes as 1D manifolds.)

---

EDIT: Here is my atlas for the square, consisting of two charts, that I claim is a $C^\infty$-atlas.

Let $Q$ denote the unit square in $\mathbb R^2$, i.e., $Q=\{(x,0)\cup(1,x)\cup(x,1)\cup(0,x)|0\leq x\leq1]\}$ (ordered pairs denote points in $\mathbb R^2$, not intervals). Equip this set with the topology inherited from the standard topology on $\mathbb R^2$.

For simplicity, let $A=Q\backslash(0,0), B=Q\backslash(0,1)$.

Here are my two charts:

$(A,\phi_A:A\to\mathbb R)$

$(x,0)\mapsto x$

$(1,x)\mapsto 1+x$

$(x,1)\mapsto 3-x)$

$(0,x)\mapsto 4-x)$

$\,$

$(B,\phi_B:B\to\mathbb R)$

$(1,x)\mapsto x$

$(x,1)\mapsto 2-x)$

$(0,x)\mapsto 3-x)$

$(x,0)\mapsto 3+x$

I'd rather not go through the painstaking task of writing out the chart transition maps from $A$ to $B$ and vice versa, but I think it's straightforward to see that they are $C^\infty$ maps from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: The square, as a topological submanifold of the plane with its usual shape, is NOT a smooth submanifold and is not diffeomorphic to the circle.

Comment: Suppose I equip it with two charts: one assigns each point its path length (traversed along the square) starting from corner A, going clockwise; the other does the same, but starting at corner B. Aren't these two charts $C^\infty$-compatible?

Comment: Did you try doing the computation at the points corresponding to the corners $C$ and $D$? You're gluing two straight line segments together somehow. How do they close up?

Comment: @TedShifrin I just updated the post with an edit to specify my charts. I think there is no doubt that the two charts are $C^\infty$-compatible.

Comment: OK, so what makes you think this is actually a square shape?

Comment: @TedShifrin $Q=\{(x,0)\cup(1,x)\cup(x,1)\cup(0,x)|0\leq x\leq1]\}$. What would better qualify as a square?

Answer (score 1):

Using your notation, you're right that you can define an atlas for $Q$ that makes it diffeomorphic to $S^1$ with the usual smooth structure. However, there isn't a smooth bijective map $S^1 \rightarrow Q \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ since the ambient space determines whether a map is smooth or not. In fact, a smooth manifold is just a Hausdorff topological space together with a smooth atlas, so ignoring the rest of $\mathbb{R}^2$ allows you to give it different smooth structures. Some textbooks emphasize this with notation like $(M, \{\phi_i\}_{i \in I})$. Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't understand the justification behind your statement "the ambient space determines whether a map is smooth." From the definitions I can see, chart transition maps determine whether a manifold is smooth.

Comment: To say that $S^1$ is diffeomorphic to $Q \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is to give a smooth map $S^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ with image $Q$. However, this isn't possible at the corners. The derivative of such a map going into the corner will be parallel to one axis while the derivative on the way out will be parallel to the other. Hence it can't have a continuous derivative. The point is that you're taking the derivative with reference to the whole ambient space $\mathbb{R}^2$, not just the subset $Q$.

Comment: Why is there any need to inherit differentiable structure from $\mathbb R^2$? Based on all the technical definitions I can find, given a starting topological space (the square-shaped collection of points in $\mathbb R^2$ indicated), we then equip it with charts and all differentiability properties depend on chart transition maps. Am I wrong? Where in the definition of smooth manifolds does it say anything about inheriting differentiable properties from the embedding space?

Comment: To be concrete, I should add I'm learning from Loring Tu's "An Introduction to Manifolds."

Answer (score 1):

Take the square equipped with the subspace topology from the plane $\mathbb R^2$. Purely as a *topological space*, the square is homeomorphic to the circle, so the two are topologically indistinguishable. Hence when you say "the square" and talk about its "corners", you are referencing more than just its topology. When you specify the square as a subset of $\mathbb R^2$ as you did [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3415893/what-s-wrong-with-this-proof-that-a-square-is-diffeomorphic-to-a-circle#comment7025419_3415893) it is not clear what structure you equip it with: just the subspace topology, or something more?

Fix a $C^\infty$ manifold $(X,\mathcal O_X)$, where $\mathcal O_X$ denotes the $C^\infty$ structure. Suppose $Y$ is a *topological manifold* (merely a topological space with a *property* but no extra structure) homeomorphic to $X$. In your context $X$ would be the circle with its usual $C^\infty$ structure and $Y$ would be the square. You can use *any* homeomorphism $f:X\cong Y$ to transport the $C^\infty$ structure from $X$ to $Y$ and get a $C^\infty$ manifold $(Y,f_\ast\mathcal O_X)$, but from a $C^\infty$ perspective this creature is just a replication of $(X,\mathcal O_X)$.

But suppose your topological manifold $Y$ is a subspace of the plane, like the square $Y\subset \mathbb R^2$. The output $(Y,f_\ast\mathcal O_X)$ of the above procedure is indifferent to this information. Your intuition, on the other hand, *relies* on the subspace inclusion $Y\subset \mathbb R^2$ because it implicitly uses the differentiable structure on $\mathbb R^2$ to identify the corners.

Here's a way to identify the corners using the *differentiable structure on the ambient space*: the square does not admit differentiable curves through its corners. Indeed observe that there is no differentiable curve $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\to \mathbb R^2$ onto a neighborhood in the square (!) of a corner. The reason for this is that the one sided derivatives at zero are vectors in $\mathbb R^2$ with different directions (each is in the direction of a different side of the square). On the other hand, the circle has the $C^\infty$ parametrization $\theta\mapsto (\cos \theta,\sin \theta)$.